# How to define parameters in Angular components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a component `modal` which has a `darkUnderneath` property. I'm trying to bind it using `[darkUnderneath]="true"` in my parent component's template and am getting:

> Can't bind to 'darkUnderneath' since it isn't a known property of 'modal'.

Do I need to use the `@Output` decorator? I tried defining `darkUnderneath` with and without the `@Output` decorator from `@angular/core`.

```html
<modal [darkUnderneath]="blah"></modal>
```

```js
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  darkUnderneath: boolean = false;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `@Input` decorator.

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  darkUnderneath: boolean = false;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, when you want to pass data from a child component to a parent component, you need to use the @Output() decorator along with an EventEmitter. However, it seems there might be a slight confusion in your question. If you want to pass data from the parent component to the child component, you use @Input() decorators, not @Output().

To clarify both scenarios, here's the proper way to use @Input() and @Output() decorators for data passing between child and parent components:

Passing data from Parent to Child (using @Input()):
Parent Component (parent.component.ts):

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: '<app-child [dataFromParent]="data"></app-child>',
})
export class ParentComponent {
  data: string = "Data from Parent";
}
```

Child Component (child.component.ts):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '<p>{{ dataFromParent }}</p>',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() dataFromParent: string;
}
```

I hope it will help you to understand clearly